# Различие в значении глаголов "движения".

Tags: семантика

Плывёт по реке-плавает по реке, мальчик бегает-мальчик бежит, птица летит-птица летает, ребёнок ходит-ребёнок идёт и т. д. Объясните, пожалуйста, различия в значениях. А также различие в значении  предложений типа: 1. Я знаю человека, который работает в школе и 2. Я знаю человека,  работающего в школе. Понятно, что в первом примере мы имеем дело со сложноподчинённым предложением с придаточным определительным, а во втором примере -     с простым предложением, в составе которого есть причастный оборот. Но меня интересует стилистическое различие. Прошу учесть, что я не русский и живу в той  среде,где нет русскоязычного населения, но люблю русский язык и слежу за вашим сайтом "Русский язык" и являюсь его подписчиком

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Различие в значении состоит в том, что одни глаголы подразумевают направленное движение (плывёт, бежит, летит, идёт), в то время как другие обозначают действие, характер совершения которого не имеет значения (плавает, летает и т. д.). Действие, описываемое глаголами второй группы, может менять направление, не иметь цели. Эти глаголы также могут обозначать способность субъекта совершать то или иное действие (ребёнок ходит, птица летает). Однако это всего лишь мое мнение.

Небольшое различие между двумя приведенными предложениями заключается в том, что использование причастных оборотов более характерно для книжного стиля, нежели для разговорного, который предпочтет сложное предложение.

Надеюсь, что я Вам немного помогла.

Comment: Я удовлетворён вашим ответом. Благодарю вас.

Comment: Не стоит благодарности:).

Answer (score 2):

Согласна с предыдущим ответом. Могу лишь уточнить, что глаголы типа "плывёт, бежит, летит, идёт" в русском языке называются однонаправленными, т.к. они обозначают движение в определенном/одном направлении. А им противопоставляются глаголы разнонаправленные, т.е. такие, которые не передают своей семантикой определенного направления. Если не ошибаюсь, термины "однонаправленные/разнонаправленные" глпголы принадлежит В.В.Виноградову.

Comment: Я разделяю мнение уважаемой Ольги. Например: рыба плавает, птица летает. Здесь разностороннее движение. Эти движения-характерные особенности указанных животных. Возьмём предложение: рыба плывёт, птица летит. В этих предложениях мы наблюдаем за движением этих животных  в каком-то одном и том же направлении.

Answer (score 2):

Придаточное предложение позволяет выразить БОЛЕЕ ТОНКИЕ ОТТЕНКИ СМЫСЛА, попробуем это рассмотреть на примерах.

Вариант 1. Я знаю человека, РАБОТАЮЩЕГО в школе.  Смысл сообщения до конца неясен.

Вариант 2. Используя придаточное предложение, этот смысл можно уточнить.

(1) Этот человек работает в школе, а этот  в институте.  Вы их знаете? - Я знаю  ТОГО человека, КОТОРЫЙ работает в школе. Пара ТОТ...КОТОРЫЙ имеет ВЫДЕЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ значение.

(2) Мне нужен человек, который работает в школе. - Я знаю человека, КОТОРЫЙ работает в школе. Это  РАСПРОСТРАНИТЕЛЬНОЕ предложение, здесь  нельзя использовать указательное слово.

Сравнить: У ворот мы увидели собаку, которая начала громко на нас  лаять.  Но нельзя сказать: У ворот мы увидели ту собаку, которая начала громко на нас лаять.

Comment: >(1) Этот человек работает в школе, а этот в институте. Вы их знаете? - Я знаю ТОГО человека, КОТОРЫЙ работает в школе. Пара ТОТ...КОТОРЫЙ имеет ВЫДЕЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ значение.

Причем указательное слово "того" можно опустить.

>(2) Мне нужен человек, который работает в школе. - Я знаю человека, КОТОРЫЙ работает в школе. Это РАСПРОСТРАНИТЕЛЬНОЕ предложение, здесь нельзя использовать указательное слово.

Да, нельзя, но зато здесь придаточное предложение можно заменить причастным оборотом. 
В этом и состоит семантическое различие между этими фразами. Вы попали в точку, София!

Answer (score 1):

salam,

Если обобщить все сказанное про глаголы, то по общей схеме однонаправленные означают действие, происходящее один раз в конкретный момент времени и, как следует из их названия, обычно имеющие конкретную цель движения: *"Я иду в парк", "По небу летела птица", "льдина плыла по реке" - и т.д.* Без указания места или цели обычно не употребляется, а в случае такого употребления означает способность (*"Я плыву!"* = Я научился плавать). Иногда эта форма используется для обозначения долженствования: *"Завтра я лечу в Нью-Йорк"*

Парные к ним глаголы могут означать: а) способность к такому движению (*"птица летает","А корабль плывет"*), б) действие совершаемое или совершавшееся неоднократно и/или постоянно (*"дети хотят в школу", "Этот пилот летал на самолете Ту-144"*), в) разнонаправленное или бесцельное движение (*"В воздухе летают снежинки"*).

В современном языке изредка встречаются отступления от этих правил, но они обычны понятны по контексту (*"Ветер гонит снежинки"* = гоняет). Для иностранца это может быть тонким моментом, я отдельно не разбираю, чтобы не заморочить голову.

Следует, впрочем, иметь в виду, что у разных глаголов движения (а их по разным источникам насчитывают шестнадцать и более пар)могут быть некоторые особенности употребления. Так например, пару *вертеть-вращать* иногда относят к парным глаголам движения, но в современном языке эти глаголы почти синонимичны.

Что касается разницы между  фразами *"Я знаю человека, который работает в школе"* и *"Я знаю человека, работающего в школе"*, то помимо указанного различия в стиле вариант с придаточным предложением иногда может означать выбор из нескольких, причастный оборот такого обычно не предполагает.

Конкретно в Вашем примере, если кому-то покажут несколько фотографий, то *"Я знаю человека, работающего в школе"* означает скорее всего, что отвечающий лично знает именно того человека, который работает в школе и сообщает об этом знании. Ответ *"Я знаю человека, который работает в школе"* означает, что говорящий знает о том, что некто названный работает в школе, т.е. информирует о месте работе этого, возможно и неизвестного ему человека. Это очень тонкое различие, оно не всегда и не всем видно, часто теряется, но Вы о том и просили. Впрочем, тут, пожалуй, дело не столько в паре "придаточное предложение - причастный оборот", сколько в смысловых тонкостях глагола "знать". Для других пар предложений подобного типа можно усмотреть какие-то другие стилистические особенности употребления.

Не утомил, надеюсь?

Comment: >"Я плыву!" = Я научился плавать

Спорная трактовка. Конечно, человек, только что научившийся плавать, может радостно воскликнуть "Я плыву!". Но это восклицание так или иначе может быть употреблено только по отношению к непродолжительному действию, которое характеризуется направленностью, и может не иметь дополнительной семантической нагрузки.

>Иногда эта форма используется для обозначения долженствования: "Завтра я лечу в Нью-Йорк"

Мне кажется, здесь речь не идет ни о каком долженствовании. Однонаправленные глаголы в такого рода пропозициях обозначают всего-навсего запланированное действие

Comment: А в остальном опубликованное Вами исследование внушает уважение к проделанной работе.